# Sql Server peer to peer replication error 21679

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, database-replication, high-availability

After i set up distributor database on my local server , i created a publication on local server based on peer to peer transaction replication and then i go through making subscribers. When i  try to create subscriber on a server named "Sqlserver2012" , the error occurred on Initialization with this text:

### " TITLE: New Subscription Wizard

SQL Server could not create a subscription for Subscriber '****\SQLSERVER2012'.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Peer-to-peer publications only support a '@sync_type' parameter value of 'replication support only', 'initialize with backup' or 'initialize from lsn'.
The subscription could not be found.
Changed database context to 'Centeral'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 21679)"

What should i do?

Many thanks prior to your answers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the section ***Considerations for Using Peer-to-Peer Replication*** in [Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx), subscriptions must be initialized by using a backup or with the **replication support only** option.

> Subscriptions must be initialized by using a backup or with the
>   'replication support only' option. For more information, see
>   [Initialize a Transactional Subscription Without a Snapshot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75c8c1f8-60bc-44a8-944b-d18d1f6bda11).

You are currently attempting to initialize Peer-to-Peer subscription with a snapshot (sync_type automatic) using the New Subscription Wizard which is not allowed.

I suggest using the [Configure Peer-to-Peer Topology Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181501.aspx) to add new peer nodes to your topology.  Instructions on how to use the Configure Peer-to-Peer Topology Wizard to configure your Peer-to-Peer topology can be found in [How to: Configure Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152536.aspx).

Alternatively, you can configure your Peer-to-Peer topology using T-SQL which is covered in [How to: Configure Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146914.aspx).

Comment: This excellent video shows how to configure a peer-to-peer replication https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKFscT09T44